# How to change the style of the window close/minimize/resize buttons in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, colors, window, minimize

In a standard Cocoa window, is it possible to change the colors of the close, minimize, and resize window buttons from the textured, glossy, gumdrop style to a simple red, yellow, and green color with no gradient/gloss?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way so you've gotta do your own custom drawing.

Check out [How to draw custom window controls (close, minimize, and zoom buttons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471000/how-to-draw-custom-window-controls-close-minimize-and-zoom-buttons) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

No.  But you can create a custom borderless window and create buttons if your liking and connect them to the same actions.